# how to find out the nofile limit for a apache user in Linux

Tags: apache

How can i find out the ulimit for apache user.

Apache user have the shell `/sbin/nologin`

What is the difference between `hard` and `soft` limits in ulimit?

Comment: Stackoverflow is probably not the correct forum for this question.

Answer (score 0):

A hard limit can only be raised by root (any process can lower it). So it is useful for security: a non-root process cannot overstep a hard limit. But it's inconvenient in that a non-root process can't have a lower limit than its children.
A soft limit can be changed by the process at any time. So it's convenient as long as processes cooperate, but no good for security.

Hope my answer helps :)